# Copy two nodes from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a input XML as below

input XML

```
<description-page>
    <noted>12000 </noted>
    <noted>15000</noted>
    <noted>NOTE</noted>
</description-page>
<idescription-note>
<noted>12000</noted>
<noted>15000</noted>
<noted>ENG CHG</noted>
</idescription-note>
```

I want to my output as

```
<sample>
<input>
    <noted>12000</noted>
    <noted>12000</noted>
</input>
<input>
    <noted>15000</noted>
    <noted>15000</noted>
</input>
<input>
    <noted>NOTE</noted>
    <noted>ENG CHG</noted>
</input>
</sample>
```

So here Every description-page (noted) required idescription-note (noted) element

What i have doing right now is in xslt

```
<xsl-template match="description-page | idescription-note>
```

this is how i am trying  my xslt but i am not getting struggle in how to match two nodes.

Please guide me here.

Regards
Karthic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position()` to synchronise the relative positions of the `description-page` and `idescription-note` nodes, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="description-page">
    <sample>
        <xsl:for-each select="noted">
            <input>
                <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()" />
                <noted>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//description-page/noted[$position]/text()"/>
                </noted>
                <noted>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//idescription-note/noted[$position]/text()"/>
                </noted>
            </input>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </sample>
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT** The below also achieves this without for-each

```
<xsl:template match="description-page">
    <sample>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="noted"/>
    </sample>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="noted">
    <input>
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()" />
        <noted>
            <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
        </noted>
        <noted>
            <xsl:value-of select="//idescription-note/noted[$position]/text()"/>
        </noted>
    </input>
</xsl:template>

<!--Suppress the description-page tree entirely-->
<xsl:template match="idescription-note">
</xsl:template>
```

I haven't tried with large xml, but with your sample

- foreach: Stylesheet execution time: 94.91 ms
- apply-templates : Stylesheet execution time: 94.93 ms

So much of a muchness? One thing with performance is to replace the `//idescription-note` path with your real full path to this node.

Comment: hi @nonnb  instead of for-each is there any method because if am using for-each for xml  i will have lot's of data I am thinking this may slow down my process is that any other method can we use

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is

```
<root>
<description-page>
    <noted>12000 </noted>
    <noted>15000</noted>
    <noted>NOTE</noted>
</description-page>
<idescription-note>
<noted>12000</noted>
<noted>15000</noted>
<noted>ENG CHG</noted>
</idescription-note>
</root>
```

then the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="id-notes" select="//idescription-note/noted"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <sample>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="description-page/noted"/>
  </sample>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="description-page/noted">
  <input>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$id-notes[$pos]"/>
  </input>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs

```
<sample>
   <input>
      <noted>12000 </noted>
      <noted>12000</noted>
   </input>
   <input>
      <noted>15000</noted>
      <noted>15000</noted>
   </input>
   <input>
      <noted>NOTE</noted>
      <noted>ENG CHG</noted>
   </input>
</sample>
```